# Doxygen: multiple \mainpage blocks in a C++ project

Tags: c++, doxygen

I wasn't able to determine what the behavior of doxygen is regarding the `\mainpage` section, in two cases:

1. If you specify no `\mainpage` section, does it use any other page instead and if so how is this picked?
2. What if two files both specify a `\mainpage` section?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\mainpage` command specifies content used to customise the index page, so if you lack one it's just a blank page with the normal Doxygen header and footer.

I think the safest thing to say about having multiple `\mainpage` commands is that it is *undefined* in the classic sense of yielding unpredictable results depending on version and platform. Similarly, I've had weird results when I accidentally created more than one `\page` command with the same page name.

**Further Thought**

Prompted by [answering another Doxygen question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558972/good-way-to-document-undef-in-doxygen/3690275#3690275), remember you can get Doxygen to obey the preprocessor directives so you can have #if conditionals protect the multiple mainpage directives and run different config files over the same code base, where the config files define one of several flag values.

I have used this *generate the docs from different perspectives* approach to publish [Macintosh](http://www.oofile.com.au/oofile_ref/html/) and [Windows-oriented](http://www.oofile.com.au/oofile_ref/htmlwin/) versions of the same reference.

Comment: Also, starting with doxygen 1.8.3 the directive "USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE" in doxygen's config file can configure which file is used as mainpage, this avoids the need of preprocessor directives.